# Where should I put \usepackage statements in template?

Tags: templates

I am writing a template for my reports. I have created a cls file for my document style and a sty file to store my commands. Other than these, I also need to import 20+ packages (that I always need to use in every report) in the template. What is a good practice to put these \usepackage statements in template? I think of 4 solutions below, is any one of them regarded as a good practice?

```latex
\documentclass{myclass} % Solution 1: Put all \usepackage or \RequirePackage statements in myclass.cls
\usepackage{mypackage} % Solution 2: Put all \usepackage or \RequirePackage statements in mypackage.sty

\input{commonpackagestouse.tex} % Solution 3: Put all \usepackage statements in a tex file and input this file at the beginning of every report

% Solution 4: Copy all \usepackage statements to every report
\usepackage{favouritepackage1}
\usepackage{favouritepackage2}
\usepackage{favouritepackage3}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

solution 1 or 2 would normally be the best but which of those depends on what you are doing.

For example any package that is required to implement the structures used by the class should be included into the class (solution 1). So for example if you need `expl3` to define something, or the class always used links or images, require `expl3` or `hyperref`  or `graphicx` into the class.

If on the other hand you have some more independent features that you personally use but potentially other people using the class might not want, then put them all in a package.
So for example if you prefer stix math fonts but the class would work equally well with stix or computer modern math, then it might be simpler to keep that `\RequirePackage{stix2}` out of the class, and put it in your package. An alternative of course would be to make the font choice an option to the class, but that is more work for at most cosmetic gain.